# Can't install ppa:utouch-team/utouch on Lucid

Tags: 10.04, ppa, apt

I am trying to install an Apple Magic Trackpad using the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicTrackpad).

I would use these command.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:utouch-team/utouch
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ginn
```

But on the update  I get these errors.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/user/ppa-name/ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-i386/Packages.gz  404  Not Found
```

How do I resolve this? I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: You get the error because the PPA only provides ginn for Maverick and Natty, and not for 10.04. I am afraid you'll have to upgrade to a more recent version.

Comment: @mikewhatever You should consider making your comment an answer. It is correct.

Answer (score 3):

You get the error because the PPA only provides ginn for Maverick and Natty, and not for 10.04. I am afraid you'll have to upgrade to a more recent version.
I'd recommend 11.10, the latest stable release.